# how to pass a parameter from mouseClicked?

Tags: java

i'm using java3D and want to pass the ID of clicked items to my class. however it doesn't succeed. it can print the ID and also can pass it to the string text. but  it says nullPointerException in the line game.btClicked(text); how can i pass the ID to my class?

```
public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener {

  private Game game;
  private String text;

  public GUI(Game game /*...*/) {

    this.game = game;
    //.......
  }

  //.......
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    pickCanvas.setShapeLocation(e);
    Primitive pickedShape = null;
    PickResult result = pickCanvas.pickClosest();

    if (result != null) {
      pickedShape = (Primitive) result.getNode(PickResult.PRIMITIVE);
    }

    //actions to be carried out when object is clicked
    if (pickedShape != null) {
      System.out.println("clicked: " + pickedShape.getName());
      String text = pickedShape.getName();
      System.out.println(text);
      game.btClicked(text);
    } else {
    }
  }
}
```

public class Game {

```
public Game(){
```

//.......

}

```
public void btClicked(String text) {
    spielfeld.disableAll();
    int buttonNr = Integer.parseInt(text);
    System.out.println("step: "+step+ " nr: "+buttonNr);
   // .......
```

}
}

the following is the stack trace:

clicked: 38

38

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
at spiel.Game.btClicked(Game.java:403)

at spiel.SpielGUI.mouseClicked(GUI.java:552)

at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

that is quite a lot, but the most is due to other problems, I'm coding a new GUI for the game so there are still some code to be changed.  so just look at the first lines.
"GUI.java:552" refers to "game.btClicked(text);"
"Game.java:403" refer  to "spielfeld.disableAll();"  but I'm sure this line is OK.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We'd need the complete stack trace of your error, and certainly the code of `Game::btClicked` to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a constructor in the code your provided. You have a method that looks very much like a constructor. I'm assuming Game isn't getting initialised.

A constructor doesn't define a return type. In your case you have

```
public void GUI(Game game ....)
```

When you actually need

```
public GUI(Game game ....)
```

Here's an example:

```
public class GUI {
    boolean b = false;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI g = new GUI();
        System.out.println(g.b);
    }
    public void GUI() {
        b = true;
    }
}
```

Provides output:

```
run:
false
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Whereas the correct constructor would be:

```
public class GUI {
    boolean b = false;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI g = new GUI();
        System.out.println(g.b);
    }
    public GUI() {
        b = true;
    }
}
```

Which gives:

```
run:
true
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: I like to call these "pseudo-constructors". Good pick-up. 1+

Comment: I'm sorry that i typed this by hand and made a mistake "public void GUI(Game game ....)"  but  in my code there is actually no "void" here, so the problem is not in constructor. but thank you anyway;)

Comment: @andreas In that case we'll need a stack trace to provide any real assistance. If you aren't doing already, look into using an IDE. It will let you use a debugger to step through the code. If you're looking to code professionally, debugging is a must.